# python: Counting the amount of vowels or consonants in a user input word

Tags: python

I'm a freshman in college, who's taking a python coding class. Currently I'm working on making a program count the amount of vowels or consonants based on a user's input to determine the mode.

currently, I've made two lists, and I'm trying to find out how to program python to count the vowels/consonants.

This is what I have so far - please keep in mind, I've worked on both ends, and the center is where the counting goes.

```
#=======================================#
#Zane Blalock's Vowel/Consonants Counter#
#=======================================#

print("Welcome to the V/C Counter!")

#Make List
vowels = list("aeiouy")
consonants = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvexz")

complete = False
while complete == False:
    mode = input("What mode would you like? Vowels or Consonants?: ").lower().strip()
    print("")
    print("You chose the mode: " + str(mode))
    print("")
    if mode == "vowels":
        word = input("Please input a word: ")
        print("your word was: " + str(word))
        print("")



        choice = input("Are you done, Y/N: ").lower().strip()
        if choice == "y":
            complete = True
        else:
            print("Ok, back to the top!")
    elif mode == "consonants":
        word = input("please input a word: ")
        print("your word was: " + str(word))
        print("")


        choice = input("Are you done, Y/N: ").lower().strip()
        if choice == "y":
            complete = True
        else:
            print("Ok, back to the top!")
    else:
        print("Improper Mode, please input a correct one")

print("Thank you for using this program")
```

Comment: Yeah, no one cares about the bookends. Only the function that does the work matters.

Comment: None of the code you've pasted pertains to counting characters. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I removed it because nothing was working. (Hence where I said the big chunk spaces were where the good would go.)

What I was doing before is making using similar questions I found on google such as the .count() method, but from what I found, the particular set-up was not working.

I found one of the answers that makes more sense that I'm to test. 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
number_of_consonants = sum(word.count(c) for c in consonants)

number_of_vowels = sum(word.count(c) for c in vowels)
```

Comment: This is better than my solution using filter()

Comment: A small change will make your solution a bit faster. Instead of generator use the exact list sum([word.count(c) for c in consonants]). You can afford to do that as the list is not too big.

Comment: @spicavigo - are you sure the list solution is faster? With consonants and "hello world" it is 17% slower. But with consonants and `string.letters * 1000` it is about the same speed.

Comment: I think mine would bite yours :), regex rocks!

Comment: `sum(1 for c in vowels)`

Answer (score 3):

```
if mode == "vowels":
    print(len(filter(lambda x: x in vowels, word)))
else:
    print(len(filter(lambda x: x in consonants, word)))
```

So I timed my and eumiro's solution. His is better

```
>> vc=lambda :sum(word.count(c) for c in vowels)
>> vc2=lambda : len(filter(lambda x: x in vowels, word))
>> timeit.timeit(vc, number=10000)
0.050475120544433594
>> timeit.timeit(vc2, number=10000)
0.61688399314880371
```

Comment: Good and concise solution, but a novice in Python probably will not understand it.  It would be nice to add a few sentences explaining the code.

Comment: ^
Exactly, but references non the less are always a good thing! I've actually found some "lambda" things from other similar questions, and was actually reading up on the documentation of it. Non the less, thank you for all of the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using regex would be an alternative:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]','there wont be any wovels in the result') 
['t', 'h', 'r', 'n', 't', 'b', 'n', 'v', 'l', 's', 'n', 't', 'h', 'r', 's', 'l', 't']
```

If you take its length your problem is solved.

```
text = 'some text'

wovels = 'aeiou'
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'

from re import findall
wovelCount = len(findall('[%s]' % wovels, text))
consonatCount = len(findall('[%s]' % consonants, text))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution which counts consonants and vowels, while excluding punctuation explicitly.

```
from string import punctuation

x = 'This is an example sentence.'

table = str.maketrans('', '', punctuation)
x = x.translate(table).lower().replace(' ', '')
vowels = set('aeiou')

consonants = sum(i not in vowels for i in x)
vowels = sum(i in vowels for i in x)

print(consonants)  # 14
print(vowels)      # 9
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey, yep was still editing - also added trivial vowels solution. Thks

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Jun 27 2011, 13:20:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = "asfdrrthdhyjkae"
>>> vowels = "aeiouy"
>>> consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvexz"
>>> nv = 0
>>> nc = 0
>>> for char in a:
...     if char in vowels:
...         nv += 1
...     elif char in consonants:
...         nc += 1
...         
>>> print nv
4
>>> print nc
11
>>>
```

Comment: What if I add 'y' in both 'vowels' and 'consonants'? ;)

Comment: then do not use elif, use if and you will get y counted in both nv or nc. But why you want to do that? In any case the OP seems to consider y as a vowel.

Answer (score 0):

Most other answers seem to count each character separately and then sum up the results, which means the code has to iterate over the input string many times and is somewhat inefficient. More efficient would be to count all occurences of all characters in one go, using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

s = "This is an example sentence."

counter = collections.Counter(s)

consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'
num_consonants = sum(counter[char] for char in consonants)
# result: 14

vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
num_vowels = sum(counter[char] for char in vowels)
# result: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

How about list comprehension with **regular expressions**?

```
import re
mystr = 'Counting the amount of vowels or consonants in a user input word'
len(re.findall('[aeiou]', mystr, flags=re.I)) # gives the number of vowels
len(re.findall('[b-d]|[f-h]|[j-n]|[p-t]|[v-z]', mystr, flags=re.I)) #gives the number of consonants
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def main():
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
    txt_input = input('Enter a sentence or a word: ').lower()
    vowel = sum(txt_input.count(i) for i in vowels)
    consonant = sum(txt_input.count(i) for i in consonants)
    print("Number of vowels in the string: ",vowel)
    print("Number of consonants in the string: ",consonant)

main()
```

Comment: when including a code block you will want to either include comments explaining your code or some exposition around your code block explaining your solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
u=input("your sentence:\n")
punctl=[]
vo=["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]
punct=[",",":",".","(",")","/","&",";","''","!","?","@"]
vf=[]
of=[]
us=(u.split())
for i in range(0,len(us)):
li=list(us[0])
   for i in range(0,len(li)):
        if ((li[0]) in vo)==True:
            vf.append((li[0]))
             li.remove((li[0]))
        else:
             of.append((li[0]))
             li.remove((li[0]))
         us.remove((us[0]))
no=0
lele=len(of)
for i in range(0,lele-1):
    a=(of[no])
    if (a in punct)==True:
        of.remove(a)
        punctl.append(a)
        no=no+1
    if (a in punct)==False:
        no=no+1
print("Number of vowels:",len(vf))
print("Vowels:",vf)
print("Number of consonants:",len(of))
print("Consonants:",of)
print("Number of punctuations:",len(punctl))
print("Punctuation:",punctl)
```

#partly complete.may be unnacurate

Comment: Welcome.  Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer to the question. Since there is often more than one answer provided, it usually helps the question asker by providing a short description of what your solution does and why it's best.