# List comprehension to count consonants

Tags: python

**Is there a more pythonic way to complete this task?** 

I am given an sentence as shown below and I have to count the amount of consonants which would be 14 in this case. I am certain there is way to reduce the amount of lines but cannot seem to figure out how.

### Attempt so far

```
def main():
    s = "This is an example sentence."
    vowels = 'aeiou.'
    lines = s.strip().split()
    word = "".join(lines)
    print(len([l for l in word if l not in vowels]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This line little shorter: `print(sum(l not in vowels for l in word))`

Comment: @Aran-Fey its not a duplicate as the user with that issue is looking for vowels as well as cononants. It also is hard to find what the answer was for that problem.

Comment: @KyleMcCann Plenty of the answers in that question count consonants and vowels separately. I'm sure you can find one that does exactly what you want - I found at least three.

Comment: @KyleMcCann, FYI, I added another solution to the dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49917606/9209546

Comment: If you want it to be more efficient, use a set: `vowels = set('aeiou')`